# Coping with gestational diabetes

Tags: health, pregnancy, parents, coping, diabetes

I had never been diabetic, but failed the glucose tolerance test during my pregnancy and have been diagnosed with Gestational Diabetes.
I am under the care of a specialist and am on insulin and testing my blood sugar levels several times throughout the day, as instructed.  It has been making me feel tired. 
I am not asking for dietary advice, I am under the care of a dietician.

Does anybody have any good advice or tips  for Mums with gestational diabetes and managing fatigue?

Comment: Your tiredness and diabetes may not be as strongly connected as you think. I don't know if this is your first baby or not and whether you can compare this pregnancy to a previous one, but, in general, women often feel very tired and weak during the first trimester. My wife slept around 11 hours, lay a lot during the day and felt constantly tired even without diabetes. I have a friend who, from what she says, feels even worse. You will feel better in the second and third trimester.

Comment: @Dariusz my kids are much older now, I asked this retrospectively, I do think you have a valid point and would love to see another answer here. Even is we cannot cover all the aspects of GD, it would be good to get some more info here, the bounty ends soon :)

Comment: I felt that my answer did not deserve the bounty - so I extended it. Take a look at the answer and make sure to comment if there are some mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tiredness

Tiredness and diabetes may not be very strongly connected. While rapidly changing sugar levels may introduce additional strain on your body, pregnancy puts even more stress on it on its own.

In general, women often feel very tired and weak during the first trimester. My wife slept around 11 hours, lay a lot during the day and felt constantly tired even without diabetes. I have a friend who, from what she says, feels even worse. Combine all this with morning sickness, hormones, and the psychological stress (OMG I'm going to have a baby;) - and you'll get te picture. All of this is completely normal.

### Gestational Diabetes

Gestational Diabetes has to be properly managed, otherwise it may cause undesirable effects on mother and the child.

Fortunately, a proper diet and some exercise is often enough. The daily amount of calories has to be set based on mother's BMI. The diet must consist of as little simple carbohydrates as possible, to avoid rapid spikes of blood sugar. Especially breakfasts must be chosen properly, because insulin resistance is highest in the morning.

Moderately intense physical exercise often helps to manage GD. Personally, I'd suggest aerobics (though remember, that not all exercises are good for pregnant women!) - it keeps your heart rate reasonably high and does not introduce heavy stress on your body.

As always, it is very important to follow your doctors suggestions and consult him whenever you are in doubt. All advice you can find in the Internet, including mine, may be wrong or just not applicable to your specific case.

Comment: thank you. I think you have covered the precautions, but saying what is best, but not always advisable to all.  The bounty was expiring, and I needed to award it, but I am much happier with this, and as you can see accepted this answer ty. I have seen yr contributions around the site, so thought you'd give a good answer :) pleased to meet you Yvette

Answer (score 4):

The moms I have known with GD have benefited from having a lot of protein and eating every few hours,  along with moderate exercise ( walking, swimming, yoga) and enough water, like a LOT of water.

That said, pregnancy is just hard work!  Give yourself a break and don't be afraid to ask for help.  Congratulations and good luck!